Translation for "envy"
The most common sense of the word envy is

Resentful desire of something possessed by another or others. (from Wiktionary)

e.g.

His new car excited their envy.

If we look for a translation for envy in Smith & Hall's English-Latin dictionary, we find the first option invidia, which is the etymology of envy, and also invidentia and livor.
By looking up the meanings of these words, it can be found that they all contain the meaning of hatred, which is different from the meaning of envy in English: when we envy someone, we desire something that one has, but it is unnecessary to hate that one.
So, are there any better choices to translate envy or envious in Latin?

I mean, the first word of your definition for the English word is resentful. I do think you need resentment to be envious.

@Cairnarvon Two problems: (a) the definition may say that, but at least in modern English there is often at best a very mild resentment at play, e.g. “she was the envy of all her friends” probably doesn't mean her friends really felt any invidiam towards her; but more importantly (b) English “envy” (like German „Neid“ by the way) definitely implies some longing for someone else's possessions, while invidia implies no such thing.

@IlyaDaskevics aemulor sounds good.
